Using window functions to filter by a date range
I have a table with only two columns: Date, Customer.
The table records sales, so for the same day there may be duplicate customers (they can make more than one purchase).
I want to calculate a table with the following columns:

Date
Number of different customers who have purchased on Date
Number of different customers who have purchased in the last 7 days since Date

Keep in mind that in the last 7 days a customer can appear multiple times, but it should only count once.
I'm trying to do it with window functions in BigQuery but I can't do it:
SELECT 
  DISTINCT Date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT Customer) AS test_day,
  COUNT(DISTINCT Customer) OVER (ORDER BY Date RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 6 DAY PRECEDING  AND CURRENT ROW) AS test_week

from table
GROUP BY 1

The error is:

ORDER BY key must be numeric in a RANGE-based window with OFFSET
PRECEDING or OFFSET FOLLOWING boundaries, but has type DATE AND Window
ORDER BY is not allowed if DISTINCT is specified

The result I expect is a table with 3 columns, the first with a date, the second with the number of different clients on that date and the third with the number of different clients in the last week.
Sample data:
  SELECT DATE('2024-08-08') AS date, 'customer1' AS customer UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE('2024-08-07'), 'customer1' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE('2024-08-06'), 'customer2' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE('2024-08-05'), 'customer3' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE('2024-08-04'), 'customer4' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE('2024-08-03'), 'customer5' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE('2024-08-02'), 'customer6' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE('2024-08-01'), 'customer7' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE('2024-08-01'), 'customer8' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE('2024-08-01'), 'customer8'


Once this is achieved, a second step is to add columns with calculations with filters, for example. Number of different clients with French nationality on the current date, and the same for the last week.
It could be done in a rudimentary way by calculating field by field, but I'd like to think there's a way to achieve this with window functions, there are dozens of filters so this would really help me.
Thanks for your help!

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Take smaller steps. Start with test_day _or test_week.

for the first part, does order by date_diff(Date, '1970-01-01', day) range between 6 preceding... work?  won't help with distinct though.   I'd just do a self join

Create a cte where you can use Max() Over() analytic function to get the number of days since last customer activity using windowing clause for six days before actual date column value. Having that done the cte resultset could be joined to the table doing Count() aggregations and grouping by dates:
WITH      --  S a m p l e    D a t a : 
  tbl AS
    ( Select TO_DATE('2024-08-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') as a_date, 1 as customer From Dual Union All
      Select TO_DATE('2024-08-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 1 From Dual Union All
      Select TO_DATE('2024-08-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 2 From Dual Union All
      Select TO_DATE('2024-08-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 3 From Dual Union All
      --
      Select TO_DATE('2024-08-05', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 2 From Dual Union All
      Select TO_DATE('2024-08-05', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 4 From Dual Union All
      Select TO_DATE('2024-08-05', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 2 From Dual Union All
      Select TO_DATE('2024-08-05', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 3 From Dual Union All
      --
      Select TO_DATE('2024-08-06', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 3 From Dual Union All
      Select TO_DATE('2024-08-06', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 5 From Dual Union All
      Select TO_DATE('2024-08-06', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 2 From Dual Union All
      Select TO_DATE('2024-08-06', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 3 From Dual Union All
      --
      Select TO_DATE('2024-08-09', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 3 From Dual Union All
      Select TO_DATE('2024-08-09', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 3 From Dual Union All
      Select TO_DATE('2024-08-09', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 3 From Dual Union All
      Select TO_DATE('2024-08-09', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 1 From Dual
    ),

  cust_7days AS
    ( Select customer, a_date, 
             Case When a_date - 
             Nvl(Max(a_date) 
                 Over(  Order By a_date
                      Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And 1 Preceding),  
                 TO_DATE('2099-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') ) Between 1 And 6
           THEN
             a_date - 
             Nvl(Max(a_date) 
                 Over(  Order By a_date
                      Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And 1 Preceding),  
                 TO_DATE('2099-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') ) 
          END as days_passed
      From   tbl
    )

--      M a i n    S Q L : 
Select     t.a_date, 
           Count(Distinct t.customer) as cnt_cust_day,   
           Count(Distinct Case When To_Number(days_passed) Between 1 And 6 
                               Then t7.customer 
                          End) as cnt_cust_prev_6_days
From       tbl t
Left  Join cust_7days t7 ON( t7.a_date <= t.a_date )
Group By   t.a_date
Order By   t.a_date

/*      R e s u l t : 
A_DATE     CNT_CUST_DAY  CNT_CUST_PREV_6_DAYS
---------  ------------  --------------------
01-AUG-24             3                     0
05-AUG-24             3                     1
06-AUG-24             3                     2
09-AUG-24             2                     3        */

NOTE:
The code above is tested with Oracle using standard sql. There may be, however, a need to do minor adjustments to get it work within your actual context.
The cnt column for 6 previous days shows the count of different customers that are not already contained in the cnt_cust_day column, so the same customer id is not in both counting columns.
See the fiddle here.

First, calculate daily counters. We get list of dates and count per date.
Then, join source table - every day (dt) with rows between current and preceding 7 days, and group by dt.
See example



date
customer




2024-08-08
customer1


2024-08-07
customer1


2024-08-06
customer2


2024-08-05
customer3


2024-08-04
customer4


2024-08-03
customer5


2024-08-02
customer6


2024-08-01
customer7


2024-08-01
customer8


2024-08-01
customer8



with daydata as(
  select date dt,count(distinct customer) dayCnt
  from test
  group by date
)
select dt,min(dayCnt) dayCnt
  ,count(distinct customer) weekCnt
from daydata d
left join test t on t.date between dateadd(d,-7,d.dt) and d.dt
group by dt




dt
dayCnt
weekCnt




2024-08-01
2
2


2024-08-02
1
3


2024-08-03
1
4


2024-08-04
1
5


2024-08-05
1
6


2024-08-06
1
7


2024-08-07
1
8


2024-08-08
1
8



fiddle.
Example for SQL Server. I think, no specific options used, except dateadd.
Use DATE_ADD(DATE dt, INTERVAL -7 DAY)
